# How can I call a function depending on screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have 2 functions, and I want them to be called depending on the screen width.

This is what I have tried:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();

var sections = function() {
    $('.image').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this),
        x = $this.find('img').width()
        $this.width(x);
     });
};

var sectionsMobile = function() {
     $('.image').find('img').css({
           'height': 'auto',
            'width': '100%'
         });
};

function checkSize() {
  if (winWidth >= 800) {
      sections();
    }   else {
      sectionsMobile();
  }
}
jQuery(window).on('load resize', checkSize);
```

When the page loads, it works and the CSS is applied. However resizing between the 800px boundary doesn't switch between the functions.

Full demo here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/PzgdWy

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If your function should be applied on window resize, you should check out [`$(window).on('resize', yourFunc)`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(){

    if($(this).width() >= 800 )
        sections();

    else
        sectionsMobile();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line is permanently cached:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
```

Just move it inside `checkSize()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
(window).resize(function() {
 if (winWidth >= 800) {
      sections();
    }   else {
      sectionsMobile();
  }
});
```